# onchange function takes time to refresh the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a drop down box in which I am showing data from a database, when I select any data it is not refreshing the page quickly when it's selected but it refreshes the page  after 5s, can anyone help me how to fix this, below is my code:

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {    document.ready
    $("#client").on("change", function() {
        var ID=$(this).attr('id');
        var clientid=$("#client").val();
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            data: {
                clientselect: $(this).val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#display").html(data);
                window.location = '?action=clientnetworkpricelist&clientid='+clientid+'';
                $("#flash").hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Html**

```
<select name="client" id="client" style="margin:-24px 0 0 1px;background-color:#E8E8E8;width:104px;position: absolute;"> 
   <option value="">Select Client</option>
<?php

$sql=mysql_query("select * from client_list");

$clientid=$_GET['clientid'];



while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))

{


    if(strlen($_GET['clientid'])>0 && $_GET['clientid']==$row['clientid']){
    print' <option id="client" name="client" value="'.$row['clientid'].'" selected>'.$row['clientid'].' </option>';}

    else{

            print' <option id="client" name="client" value="'.$row['clientid'].'" >'.$row['clientid'].' </option>';
    }

   }



   ?>


</select>
```

Comment: you do ajax request when you your on change callback. It seems like this request takes its time to implement. Use browser debugger to see exact time for your request and then you will realize you have to speed up server-side.

Comment: Do not use mysql to work with db. better use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: What happens after `success: ` is, "wait for the request to finish, retrieve data, afterwards do window.location change" with Firefox+Firebug you can see how long it takes exactly

Comment: @DanFromGermany its takes 4s

Answer (score 4):

As kitty says, the delay is the time it takes to get the data from your database. You need to find a way to speed up the database response.

Link that might be useful:
http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1851233

Answer (score 2):

Time is needed to implement ajax request to server and depends on time needed for you server-side code to response + network transport and stuff.